JavaScript loop running on console but not on code
I'm trying to make a a JS forEach loop that is supposed to run after the DOM is fully loaded, but for some reason it won't run on code but when I put the same loop on console it runs fine.
window.onload = (event) => {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("plates")
    var labelPlate = document.getElementsByName("labelPlate")

    checkboxes.forEach((i, index) => {
        if (i.checked) {

            labelPlate[index].classList.add("active")
        } else {
            labelPlate[index].classList.remove("active")
        }
    })
};

Loop is supposed to run.

Are there any errors in your console? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html in order to create a [mre].

Are the checkboxes loaded dynamically? They may not be loaded yet when this code runs.

How do you know "it won't run"?

Do you have multiple window.onload assignments? Only the last one will run, since they overwrite each other. Use window.addEventListener() to add multiple handlers.

While getElementsByName does return a live NodeList and therefore does have a forEach method on it, that method was added later on, so an older browser may not have it correctly implemented. Hard to say without the HTML on which the code runs. Use a Stack Snippet to make your code runnable here on Stack Overflow.

@HereticMonkey If the method isn't implemented you'll get an error. And it wouldn't work in the console, either.

@Barmar Thank you for the obviousness of your reply. It serves as a useful juxtaposition to what my comment actually says, which is that "an older browser may not have it correctly implemented." And implementations can differ between the console and the browser.

The reason the code works in the console and not when embedded into your page directly, is likely because the elements you're searching for are being dynamically added to the page after the load event occurs.
In the console, you're manually waiting long enough for those elements be in the DOM before running that code, but when the code is included in the page itself, the code is searching for those elements before they've made it into the DOM.
You need to modify your code, so that it fires after the dynamic elements are added (which occurs AFTER when the base html document is initially loaded).

To add to @Lonnie's answer:

You need to modify your code, so that it fires after the dynamic elements are added (which occurs AFTER when the base html document is initially loaded).

You have a few options:

Load your script at the end of the document in case it's static instead of <head>
Wait for a successful event from your framework (since you haven't mentioned any such thing here, I'll give you a framework agnostic answer)

At the end of the part of your code that generates your plates and labels do the following: (to fire a complete event)
const myCompleteEvent = new Event("plates-loaded");
document.dispatchEvent(myCompleteEvent);


Use it like so:
document.addEventListener("plates-loaded", () => {
   const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("plates");
   const labelPlate = document.getElementsByName("labelPlate");

   checkboxes.forEach((c, i) => {
     labelPlate[i].classList.toggle("active", c.checked);
   });
});





Also cleaned your code by using classList.toggle instead of add/remove :)

What's the significant difference between onload and waiting for readyState == 'complete'?

I double checked my answer and I think that was incorrect, I've adjusted it to now work using completion events :) Thanks for that catch @Barmar!

Do you really need an event for this? Just use an ordinary function, and call it after loading the elements. Or just put the code in the question after loading the elements.

That's true, but that makes a few assumptions on code access and interop. I was providing a generalizable way that can work with agnostic code on both ends that simply let anything "hook" into the completion state
